# Why does adding fromdate=<long time ago> return a different set than without it?

Tags: support, date

I've been trying to get some stats for the Windows 8 challenge over on Super User. I've noticed that there are some questions missing if I add `fromdate=0`. Why is this?

#### Without `fromdate`:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?site=superuser&tagged=windows-8&filter=total

```
{"total":807}
```

#### `fromdate=0`:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?site=superuser&tagged=windows-8&filter=total&fromdate=0

```
{"total":764}
```

#### `fromdate=1970-01-01`:

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?tagged=windows-8&filter=total&site=superuser&fromdate=1970-01-01

```
{"total":764}
```

When comparing the two sets, it seems that `fromdate` excludes questions with a negative score (`score < 0`). Is my guess correct? Why? Is this documented anywhere? Can intentionally I include questions with a negative score when filtering with `fromdate`?

Comment: Yeah, it does appear to only be taking questions with score >= 0. You can [convince it to do otherwise](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?site=superuser&tagged=windows-8&filter=total&fromdate=0&sort=votes&min=-999), but I don't think this behaviour is intentional.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks for the alternative. I'll use that for now, and probably handle sorting locally if I ever need to (assuming this isn't found to be a bug and fixed by then).